Coherent data table for yearly temperature over a period of 32 years
I am new to making data tables. I want to create a year and temperature data table. I have already attempted to my best ability but I am seeking assistance in redesigning and making it more coherent and I am open to all suggestions because in its current form I believe there is room for improvement.
This is what I have so far:

This is the code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{transparent}

\newcommand{\incfig}[1]{%
    \def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
    \import{./figures/}{#1.pdf_tex}
}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, skip=5pt, font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%for tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{everypage-1x}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % load both xcolor and colortbl
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.56cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,landscape]{geometry}

\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}% <-- new
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
%\input{arrowsnew}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{everypage-1x}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{threeparttable}




\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}


\begin{table*}[h] 
\centering
%\ra{1.3}
\begin{small}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrrrrrrrrrr@{}}\toprule
\textbf{Year} & \textbf{1990} & \textbf{1991} & \textbf{1992} & \textbf{1993} & \textbf{1994} & \textbf{1995} & \textbf{1996} & \textbf{1997} & \textbf{1998} & \textbf{1999} & \textbf{2000} & \textbf{2001} & \textbf{2002} \\ \midrule
Temperature $^\circ$C & 25 & 24.6 & 24.1 & 24.2 & 28.2 & 25.1 & 24.9& 25.3 & 26.3 & 25.2 & 27.2 & 22.5 & 27.1 \\ \midrule
\textbf{Year} & \textbf{2003} & \textbf{2004} & \textbf{2005} & \textbf{2006} & \textbf{2007} & \textbf{2008} & \textbf{2009} & \textbf{2010} & \textbf{2011} & \textbf{2012} & \textbf{2013} & \textbf{2014} & \textbf{2015} \\ \midrule
Temperature $^\circ$C & 25.5 & 26.1 & 27.1& 27.7 & 27.6 & 24.4 & 27.3 & 25.9 & 26.9 & 27 & 27.1 & 25 &30.3  \\ 
 \midrule
\textbf{Year} & \textbf{2016} & \textbf{2017} & \textbf{2018} & \textbf{2019} & \textbf{2020} & \textbf{2021} & \textbf{2022} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} & \textbf{} &  \\  \midrule
Temperature $^\circ$C & 26.6 & 26.1 & 28.6& 29.1 & 25.5 & 26.2&26.5\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{small}
\caption{Yearly December temperature data}
\end{table*}
\end{document}


Preamble: you only need a tiny subset here. As it is, you probably cause an update nightmare, esp. for novices, just to try your code. So delete what isn’t needed. // Table: As a reader I‘d find grouping by decades more natural. // Good: using booktabs.

Nitpick: the temperatures should be given with a consistent precision, so it should be “25.0” not just “25”, to match “25.1” etc. (Unless the different values were genuinely coming from different precision measurements/sources, of course, but it doesn’t look like that’s the case here.)

I would strongly consider transposing the table because it is far easier to scan a column of numbers than a row.  In that case, you would want to use the S column type from siunitx to allow the temperatures to align on the decimal place.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.56cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, skip=5pt, font=small]{caption}

\newcommand{\cels}{\textup{\textdegree C}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ @{}             c S[table-format=2.1]
                 @{\hspace{2em}} c S[table-format=2.1]
                 @{\hspace{2em}} c S[table-format=2.1] @{} }\toprule
1990 & 25   & 2001 & 22.5 & 2012 & 27   \\
1991 & 24.6 & 2002 & 27.1 & 2013 & 27.1 \\
1992 & 24.1 & 2003 & 25.5 & 2014 & 25   \\
1993 & 24.2 & 2004 & 26.1 & 2015 & 30.3 \\
1994 & 28.2 & 2005 & 27.1 & 2016 & 26.6 \\
1995 & 25.1 & 2006 & 27.7 & 2017 & 26.1 \\
1996 & 24.9 & 2007 & 27.6 & 2018 & 28.6 \\
1997 & 25.3 & 2008 & 24.4 & 2019 & 29.1 \\
1998 & 26.3 & 2009 & 27.3 & 2020 & 25.5 \\
1999 & 25.2 & 2010 & 25.9 & 2021 & 26.2 \\
2000 & 27.2 & 2011 & 26.9 & 2022 & 26.5 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Yearly December temperature data (\cels)}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Note that it's easier to answer questions about the temperatures (and spot blatant typos) with this formatting.

Perfect, I like this one. Thank you

It's obvious to the reader that 1990, 1991 and so on represent years; the figures below years are temperatures, as specified in the caption. Thus repeating “year” and “temperature” is annoying. The horizontal rules serve no purpose except making the table difficult to read; boldface is heavy and puts emphasis where it shouldn't be: temperatures are more important than year numbers (which can be inferred from context).
You have 33 pieces of data, so three lines can be filled with an equal number of items. The idea is that you have a long line of data, which is split just for convenience.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.56cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, skip=5pt, font=small]{caption}

\newcommand{\cels}{\textup{\textdegree C}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}*{11}{c}@{}}
\toprule
1990 & 1991 & 1992 & 1993 & 1994 & 1995 & 1996 & 1997 & 1998 & 1999 & 2000 \\
25   & 24.6 & 24.1 & 24.2 & 28.2 & 25.1 & 24.9 & 25.3 & 26.3 & 25.2 & 27.2 \\
\addlinespace
2001 & 2002 & 2003 & 2004 & 2005 & 2006 & 2007 & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011 \\
22.5 & 27.1 & 25.5 & 26.1 & 27.1 & 27.7 & 27.6 & 24.4 & 27.3 & 25.9 & 26.9 \\
\addlinespace
2012 & 2013 & 2014 & 2015 & 2016 & 2017 & 2018 & 2019 & 2020 & 2021 & 2022 \\
27   & 27.1 & 25   & 30.3 & 26.6 & 26.1 & 28.6 & 29.1 & 25.5 & 26.2 & 26.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Yearly December temperature data (\cels)}

\end{table}

\end{document}


You might want to use the whole text width, so the pairs are better separated:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.56cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, skip=5pt, font=small]{caption}

\newcommand{\cels}{\textup{\textdegree C}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% let TeX compute

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{11}{c}}
\toprule
1990 & 1991 & 1992 & 1993 & 1994 & 1995 & 1996 & 1997 & 1998 & 1999 & 2000 \\
25   & 24.6 & 24.1 & 24.2 & 28.2 & 25.1 & 24.9 & 25.3 & 26.3 & 25.2 & 27.2 \\
\addlinespace
2001 & 2002 & 2003 & 2004 & 2005 & 2006 & 2007 & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011 \\
22.5 & 27.1 & 25.5 & 26.1 & 27.1 & 27.7 & 27.6 & 24.4 & 27.3 & 25.9 & 26.9 \\
\addlinespace
2012 & 2013 & 2014 & 2015 & 2016 & 2017 & 2018 & 2019 & 2020 & 2021 & 2022 \\
27   & 27.1 & 25   & 30.3 & 26.6 & 26.1 & 28.6 & 29.1 & 25.5 & 26.2 & 26.5 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Yearly December temperature data (\cels)}

\end{table}

\end{document}



That looks great. Do you think there should be some seperation however between the years and temperatures? I am curious to other styles and ways of formatting this. I cant seem to find anything resembling the same context and data table on the internet. Or is this perhaps the best solution for my context.

@Rhys Since year and temperature are strictly linked, adding vertical space would make the table harder to read. I added a slightly different format.

Hmm, just doesnt look right, Its hard to explain, although obvious not, it just looks like theres no distinction between year and temperature. Would you pass this off as presentable? I only ask as I am new to making tables and really have no idea if in the scientific space this would be a acceptable presentation of this data. Thanks!

@Rhys  ASHRAE Handbook (Fundamentals) has many tables, if you want to explore. I would add in the caption the location and weather station code, if you have). Rest is a matter of taste (I like the answer), as tables should be as compact as possible.

If you were adding vertical space it would surely be between pairs of rows to more closely pair the year and its corresponding temperature.  But I'd have to ask what purpose the table serves that wouldn't be better in a graph.  Wrapping every 11 years looks nicer than after 10 and 20, but we're conditioned to think in decades, so I have my doubts
